# Angular2 getting array size from observable

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have 4 different arrays, each with varying length.  I need to figure out the array.length to know how many steps are in the current selected array. I want this to be done in the code, not in the template if possible.

step.service.ts

```
public apiURL(){
  if (this.heroID == 0){
   this.stepsUrl = 'api/stepsLiftSensor';
  } else if(this.heroID == 1){
   this.stepsUrl = 'api/stepsBucketSensor';
  } else if(this.heroID == 2){
   this.stepsUrl = 'api/stepsEmptyBucketSensor';
  } else if(this.heroID == 3) {
   this.stepsUrl = 'api/stepsFullBucketSensor';
  }
 console.log(this.stepsUrl); 
}

  getSteps(): Observable<Step[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.stepsUrl)
               .map(response => response.json().data as Step[]);
  }

  getStep(id: number): Observable<Step> {
    const url = `${this.stepsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(response => response.json().data as Step);
  }
```

calibration-detail.component.ts

Right now it goes through 11 steps, but now that the arrays are different sizes it will break like this.  I want to have it so ( currentStep < this.stepService.getSteps().length() ) but this doesn't seem to work as observable doesn't have a length property.  Is there a way to do this?

```
private currentStep: number = 0; //Variable for the current step
next() {
    //Assuming there is another step it pulls the next step up, else it says "End of steps"
    if (this.currentStep < 11) { //make sure dont go past number of steps
       this.currentStep ++; //Increments the step
       this.stepService.getStep(this.currentStep).subscribe(data => (this.mainStepText = data.name)); //Handles return and sets the data it contains to local variable
    } else {
       this.mainStepText = "Calibration Finished.";
    }
  }
```

in-memory-data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Hero } from './hero.class';
import { Step } from './step.class';
import { HeroService } from "./hero.service";
import { StepService } from "./step.service";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  hero: Hero;
  step: Step;

  private heroService: HeroService;
  private stepService: StepService;
  private route: ActivatedRoute;
  private location: Location;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {

     this.route.params
       .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
       .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }

createDb() {

      let heroes = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Lift Sensor', path: 'stepsLiftSensor'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Bucket Sensor', path: 'stepsBucketSensor'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Empty Bucket'},  
      {id: 4, name: 'Full Bucket'}
    ];

    let stepsLiftSensor = [
      {id: 1, name:  'test1'},
      {id: 2, name:  'test2'},
      {id: 3, name:  'test3'},
      {id: 4, name:  'test4'},
      {id: 5, name:  'test5'}
    ];

    let stepsBucketSensor = [
      {id: 1, name:  'test1'},
      {id: 2, name:  'test2'},
      {id: 3, name:  'test3'},
      {id: 4, name:  'test4'},
      {id: 5, name:  'test5'}
      {id: 6, name:  'test6'},
      {id: 7, name:  'test7'},
      {id: 8, name:  'test8'},
      {id: 9, name:  'test9'},
      {id: 10, name:  'test10'}
    ];  

    let stepsEmptyBucketSensor = [
      {id: 1, name:  'test1'},
      {id: 2, name:  'test2'},
      {id: 3, name:  'test3'},
      {id: 4, name:  'test4'},
      {id: 5, name:  'test5'},
      {id: 6, name:  'test6'}
    ];

    let stepsFullBucketSensor = [
       {id: 1, name:  'test1'},
      {id: 2, name:  'test2'},
      {id: 3, name:  'test3'},
      {id: 4, name:  'test4'},
      {id: 5, name:  'test5'}
    ];


    return { heroes, stepsLiftSensor, stepsBucketSensor, stepsEmptyBucketSensor, stepsFullBucketSensor };   
  }
}
```

step.class.ts

```
export class Step {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the service itself to return the length of the array along with the data (let's call it `lengthFromService`).

And you can store that length in a variable in the .ts (let's call it `arrLength`) and do your check on that variable.

so in your next() function you could do something like this:

```
this.stepService.getStep(this.currentStep).subscribe(data => {this.mainStepText = data.name; this.arrLength = data.lengthFromService});
```

If you need more help please post the code of the service, or the code of whatever function that gives the `data` to the service.

Comment: Added two more classes, is that what you wanted to see?

Comment: Yes thanks for asking, I added an answer with how I solved it.

Answer (score 2):

After re-reading your guys answers and looking at my code I ended up solving it,  I just used

```
this.stepService.getSteps().subscribe(data => (this.stepsLength = data.length));
```

and put it in the constructor for my calibration-detail.component.ts.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to follow what you want. But from what I could gather after reading it 5 times, is that you should store the length once you obtained the steps, and use that variable in your `next()` method:

```
stepsLength: number = 0;

getSteps(): Observable<Step[]> {
   return this.http.get(this.stepsUrl)
           .map(response => response.json().data as Step[])
           .do(steps => this.stepsLength = steps.length);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but when I pass it back it's undefined. I call: getArrayLength(): number { return this.stepsLength; } and store it in: private stepsLength: number = this.stepService.getArrayLength();